# difference between scipy.stats.cdf and scipy.stats.ppf

Tags: python, statistics

When I was reading different listings of hypothesis testing code, I saw that `scipy.stats.cdf/ppf` was used to do roughly same things - computing constants for stats tests. But after reading documentation I did not understand what is the difference between them and in what case use them

Answer (score 0):

The ppf is the inverse of the cdf.

```
from scipy.stats import norm
f = norm.cdf(0.7)
print ("f", f)
inv_f = norm.ppf(f)
print("inv f",  norm.ppf(f) )


OUTPUT
f 0.758036347777
inv f 0.7
```

Im not sure if I can help you with when to use them, that too broad a question, but this is their relation.